# Definition of transition kernel

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory

This is the definition of transition kernel I took from [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Random_measure)

> Being a transition kernel means that
>
> - For any fixed $ B \in \mathcal{E} $, the mapping
>   $ \omega \mapsto \zeta(\omega,B)$ is measurable function from $ (\Omega, \mathcal A) $  to
>   $(E, \mathcal E) $
> - For every fixed $ \omega \in \Omega $, the mapping
>   $ B \mapsto \zeta(\omega, B)  \quad (B \in \mathcal E)$
>   is a measure (mathematics) on $ (E, \mathcal E) $
>
> Being locally finite means that the measures
> $ B \mapsto \zeta(\omega, B) $
> satisfy $ \zeta(\omega,\tilde B) < \infty $ for all bounded measurable sets $ \tilde B \in \mathcal E $
> and for all $ \omega \in \Omega $ except some $ P $ null set.

I feel there is something wrong in the first bullet point. The definition of $\zeta$ should be

$$\zeta:\Omega\times\mathcal E\to\mathbb R$$
so I think the first bullet point should be "the mapping
$ \omega \mapsto \zeta(\omega,B)$ is measurable function from $ (\Omega, \mathcal A) $  to $(\mathbb R, \mathfrak{B}) $". Am I correct?

Comment: You are correct. :)